# Creating a list in which each list item has unique elements

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using a loop to create a list using the following code

```
for (i in 1:length(names))
{
a[i]<-filter(global,global$people_names==names[i]) %>% select(Class)
}
```

`names` is a vector and `global` is a data frame. I am comparing each element of `names` with each `people_names` and picking up the `Class`. The code works well if the values in `Class` are distinct for each `people_names`. But if a `people_names` "rocky" has classes : `class1` `class2` `class3` `class3`, I am not able to
remove the repetitions of `class3` while populating my list. Using `select(unique(Class))` does not help. Please help.

Comment: Please use `dput` to provide a reproducible example, along with expected output.

Comment: Suppose my vector has first element "rocky". So I am writing a code to find "rocky" in my data frame global$people_names and pickup another column element(column name class) corresponding to all rows with people_names as "rocky". I now create a list with each list item having the result of one pickup. I want to pick up only the distinct classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add one more pipe after the select, and then use subset() and duplicated() to remove duplicates on the offending column, so:

```
a[i]<-filter(global,global$people_names==names[i]) %>% 
    select(Class) %>%
    subset(!duplicated(Class))
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Unique could have worked if you'd wrapped the entire thing, pipes and all, in unique(); however, using unique(Class) turned the entire Class column into a short list of unique values that would no longer map meaningfully onto anything.